# Show only the hexadecimal string

Tags: python

I'm writing a code on Python to read information from a RFID, but how I'd left only the hexadecimal part?

Code:

```
import serial as s
ser = s.Serial('COM8', 9600, timeout=10000)
rfid = ser.read(13).splitlines()
print(rfid)
```

Output:

```
[b'\x024500F38EC7FF']
```

Expected Output:

```
4500F38EC7FF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just the ASCII characters you can split the string to remove the leading 0x02 character

```
>>> x = b'\x024500F38EC7FF'
>>> x[1:] # skip the first character
'4500F38EC7FF'
```

If you want the values of each character as integers,

```
>>> [ord(c) for c in x]
[2, 52, 53, 48, 48, 70, 51, 56, 69, 67, 55, 70, 70]
```

Or if you want a hexadecimal representation of each character, you can use something like

```
>>> ' '.join('%02x' % ord(c) for c in x)
'02 34 35 30 30 46 33 38 45 43 37 46 46'
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `splitlines()` returns you an array, which is what you see on `print`

Try simply `print rfid[0]`, that might do what you want.

```
>>> x = b'\x024500F38EC7FF'
>>> print(x)
4500F38EC7FF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line = [b'\x024500F38EC7FF']
line[0][1:]
```

Do you mean this way?